# Resolution of capture screen image is not retina

Tags: iphone, screen

[image]I am using the following code for capture a view on the screen but it is not as sharp as on the screen. the imageView size is 200x200point but the scale is 2.0 (with retina screen). The saved `img` size is 200x200 px. how could i make the `img` as sharp as the original one? Any help will be appreciated!

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView *)theView {

    CGRect rect = theView.frame;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [theView.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old way of creating the image context. Use this instead:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
```

The older `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` function always assumes a scale of 1.0.

Replace 'YES' with 'NO' if you need the alpha channel.

Answer (score 3):

Try like that:

```
     CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
```