# Losing quality when capturing screen

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I'm capturing a part of the screen that the app is currently showing using the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 320));
[sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, -45)];
UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The problem is, the result has reduced quality when comparing to the original screen.
How can I prevent the quality loss?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832871/resolution-of-capture-screen-image-is-not-retina

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For you info.

```
// Create a graphics context with the target size
// On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
// On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Comment: Great! Simple and well explained!